# MVVM change culture Using Binding

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, culture

I have a dropdown list with values English and Arabic. As I select any one of them it should change culture also. As we know, for English, by default we will use this.

```
1.Content ="{x:Static lang:Strings.contactNoNotValid}"
```

And for Arabic, we will add its Arabic code with the above code. That is,

```
2.Content ="{x:Static lang:Strings.ar.contactNoNotValid}"
```

Here What I want is whenever I switch English to Arabic I want to change the code from 1 to the code 2. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I think this link will be helpful.
When you change the culture, you can switch to the text corresponding to the culture using resource file.

description: https://codinginfinity.me/post/2015-05-10/localization_of_a_wpf_app_the_simple_approach
source: https://gist.github.com/jakubfijalkowski/0771bfbd26ce68456d3e

**XAML**

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{ex:Loc Foo}"/>
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
string culture = ""; // or "ar"
TranslationSource.Instance.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
```

**Resources**

- Resources.resx

  - "Foo" : "Hello"
- Resources.ar.resx

  - "Foo" : "مرحبا هناك"